# What determines the amount of power sent to a device?

Tags: power-supply, power, resistance, plug

I have various devices that draw amount different amounts of power from a micro power connector. If I have a 240V socket plugged into a device which draws 4W of power, does this mean that the power not required is "halted" by the device ? And does this pose a risk that over time the device will eventually begin to no longer resist the unused power, allowing extra volts to "fry" its circuitry ?

Comment: An OK analogy is taps from a pipe. Pressure is the same for all taps in the same area. Flow varies by tap. Turn on the tap more for more water flow. Pressure = voltage, Flow RATE = current.  Power = volts x amps = pressure x current_flow_rate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are labouring under a common misconception we often see from people who don't have a proper grasp of the basics of electricity.

Power is never PUSHED into a device, it is only DRAWN BY a device.  If you need 4W then you only draw 4W.  If you need 25GW then you try and draw 25GW. If the power supply is not capable of providing 4W, 25GW then the power supply can be damaged.

In general (unless you have special requirements and hence a special power supply), **voltage is fixed** (say 240V) and *must match the device voltage*, and **current is variable** (ONLY what the device needs at any one time). The **power is the product of the two**.

Comment: Actually that's not quite true : power is pushed - the old name for voltage is "electrical pressure" and indeed, too much "electrical pressure" will break down a device. But for a supply at the right "pressure", the device will draw only the power it needs, "turning on the tap" only enough to allow the correct current through.

Comment: @BrianDrummond The whole form of the question shows a complete lack of basic knowledge by the OP - randomly mixing volts and watts. So it's best not to confuse them with too much information at this stage.